# Mapping Multiple States to Column in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I have created project with *agile* process template, The project dashboard is customized with different column names. My Requirement is to map *multiple state to One Column*, but i am not able to see multiple state in column mapping.
please see the attached image for reference.
[image]

Comment: Hi friend, not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here. Just a remind of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) .

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid we can only map one state to the column at present but this is indeed a good suggestion. We already have a suggestion ticket about "Allow multiple states in the KanBan Board Columns" in our developer community. You can track and vote this suggestion ticket: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/627169/allow-multiple-states-in-the-kanban-board-columns.html. The product group will review these tickets regularly, and consider take it as roadmap. Thank you.

Comment: HI @walter-qian-msft,

Thanks for information, We would like top have this option option as it is available in major DevOps tools.

Comment: Hi friend, you can add your comment in [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/627169/allow-multiple-states-in-the-kanban-board-columns.html) if you have any ideas or suggestions.